# In psmatrix, dow do I connect a line to each of the parallel lines in doubleline?

Tags: pstricks, pst-node

I'm trying to create a diagram in the `psmatrix` environment which has a double line connecting to a node and then has two separate lines coming from the node, one line coming from each of the two double lines.

Here is a MWE:

```
    \documentclass{article}

    \usepackage{pst-node}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    $\psmatrix[colsep=0.3cm,rowsep=.4cm,mnode=circle]
    [mnode=dot,dotscale=.00001] \\
    [mnode=dot,dotscale=.00001] & [mnode=dot,dotscale=.00001] & [mnode=dot,dotscale=.00001] \\
    [mnode=r] && [mnode=r]
    \ncline[doubleline=true]{1,1}{2,2}
    \ncline{2,2}{3,1}
    \ncline{2,2}{3,3}
    \psset{linestyle=dashed}\ncline{2,1}{2,3}
    \endpsmatrix
    $
    \end{figure}

    \end{document}
```

It is working how I want to with the double line, however the lines from (2,2) to (3,1) and from (2,2) to (3,3) are coming from the same part of the node at (2,2). I want the line from (2,2) to (3,1) to connect to the left-hand line from the doubleline and the line from (2,2) to (3,3) to connect to the right-hand line from the doubleline.

I am processing the file through LaTeX -> PS -> PDF.

Comment: Welcome to the TeX.SX, http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx! Could you please post a complete example starting with `\documentclass...` and ending with `\end{document}` plus a note how you are processing the file. It will help us tremendously.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to achieve your goal is to `offset` each of the `\ncline`s:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pst-node}

\begin{document}

\psmatrix[colsep=0.3cm,rowsep=.4cm,mnode=circle]
  [mnode=dot,dotscale=.00001] \\
  [mnode=dot,dotscale=.00001] & [mnode=dot,dotscale=.00001] & [mnode=dot,dotscale=.00001] \\
  [mnode=r] && [mnode=r]
  \ncline[doubleline=true]{1,1}{2,2}
  \ncline[offset=-\pslinewidth]{2,2}{3,1}
  \ncline[offset=\pslinewidth]{2,2}{3,3}
  \psset{linestyle=dashed}\ncline{2,1}{2,3}
\endpsmatrix

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not understand the sense of `[mnode=dot,dotscale=.00001]`. However, you can also use `\psline` for a connection over three nodes:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-node}

\begin{document}

    $\psmatrix[colsep=0.3cm,rowsep=.4cm,mnode=circle]
     [mnode=p,name=A]\\
     [mnode=p] & [mnode=p,name=B] & [mnode=p]\\
     [mnode=r,name=C] && [mnode=r,name=D]
     \psline(A)(B)(C)
     \pcline[offset=1mm](A)(D)
     \ncline[linestyle=dashed]{2,1}{2,3}
    \endpsmatrix
    $

\end{document}
```

[image]